# Qt Android app error: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, qt, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So I am having this strange error when I try to compile my Qt application for Android. My `build.gradle` is practically (except for package name) the same as this one here https://github.com/Larpon/QtFirebaseExample/blob/master/App/platforms/android/build.gradle. When I try to compile however I get a long list of errors beginning with:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
>   > BUILD FAILED in 8s 21 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 13 up-to-date com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   >     merging dex archives:

I have read similar threads on here which suggest enabling `multiDexEnabled = true`, I have already tried and also tried to clean my app but it doesn't work. I have also tried to add `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` in the dependencies section of my `build.gradle` but no luck. Finally I have also set but nothing works.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "packagename" // Used by Firebase auto-config (the google-services.json from Firebase console)
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    //versionCode 1
    //versionName "1.0"

    //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix the problem by migrating to AndroidX as noted here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate. After modifying the necessary files the compilation error disappeared.